# Performance difference between hooks usKeyPress and useEventListener

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

The [useEventListener](https://usehooks.com/useEventListener/) hook and the [useKeyPress](https://usehooks.com/useKeyPress/) seem to have a slightly different implementation, but I'm trying to figure out which is a better tool to use for my specific use case.

I have a custom dropdown select menu, and I want to listen to the arrow down, up and enter keys. My problem, or rather question, about the useKeyPress hook, is that there are two renders that happen + I'm not really sure why there is an intermediate useState.

For instance, using the useKeyPress hook, if a user click on a down arrow, the event listeners fire off twice, one would return true, and immediately return false onKeyUp:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('keydown', downHandler);
    window.addEventListener('keyup', upHandler);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('keydown', downHandler);
      window.removeEventListener('keyup', upHandler);
    };
  }, []);
```

Also, I'm not sure why it's doing,

```
const [keyPressed, setKeyPressed] = useState(false);
```

I'm just looking for some clarification on the difference between these two, and which one to use for my use case.

Comment: These are just recipes, you can modify them to suit your needs. If all you need is an event listener for `keyPress` that calls a handler, create/customize it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Performance shouldn't be your primary concern as both are fast enough for nearly every use case they cover.

`useKeyPress` is probably not well suited for your use case as it only gives you information of when a key is pressed. It doesn't let you call a handler. It internally keeps track of the pressed state itself. But you likely want to call a handler, e.g. to change the currently selected item in your dropdown list.

> Also, I'm not sure why it's doing,
>
> `const [keyPressed, setKeyPressed] = useState(false);`

That's simply the use case. It keeps track of the pressed state of a button.

`useEventListener` is a more generic tool that lets you do the updating and state management yourself. It lets you decide what to update based on the subscribed events. You could in fact rewrite `useKeyPress` to internally use `useEventListener`.

Answer (score 0):

React works by updating state. If the `useKeyPress` hook didn't update *some* internal state then it would be incapable of returning an updated value reference and trigger a component rerender. `useKeyPress` listens for the keyDown event to toggle state to true, then listens for the keyUp event to clear that state (you don't want it stuck true.

The `useEventListener` is certainly a heavier tool; it's capable of monitoring many more events. It doesn't use internal state though, but rather requires callback handlers to be passed to it to be invoked when registered event occurs.

For a lightweight utility the `onKeyPress` is useful if you just need to trigger an effect callback in a component, but for larger projects or where you want more than to know a keyPress occurred, `useEventListener` can handle it.